# Open tab and slide down to area

Tags: jquery, tabs, anchor, accordion, slidedown

I am using jqueryResponsiveTabs that when scaled down becomes an accordian.

On the link below there is a tabbed area that on mboile becomes accordian. Rhe personalise button at the top should open the 'personalise' tab in the 'what you need to know' section and also scroll the page down to this area.

I can get it to open the tab but I can't get it to scroll down.

Any thoughts?

http://www.swimmingcover.co.uk/bag/test.html

Comment: Will u explain me in brief

Answer (score 0):

I don't get u exactly all i knew that u need some sort of accordion code. Here I have simple jquery accordion. Let me know if u get any difficulties.

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='item'>Item 1</div>
<div class='item-data'>
    <div>
        This is the content for Accordion 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class='item'>Item 2</div>
<div class='item-data'>
    <div>
        This is the content for Accordion 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class='item'>Item 3</div>
<div class='item-data'>
    <div>
        This is the content for Accordion 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class='item'>Item 4</div>
<div class='item-data'>
    <div>
        This is the content for Accordion 4
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #555;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}
.item-data {
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.active {
    background: #eee;
    color: #000;
}
.item-data div {
    margin: 30px;
}

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.item').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).next('.item-data').css('display') != 'block') {
            $('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next('.item-data').addClass('active').slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $('.active').slideUp('fast').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

I also given u link for working fiddle check this out for any reference. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cbHLX/1/)